# VSCode AngularJS Intellisense not working

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code

Installed typings globally

```
npm install -g typings.
```

Installed AngularJS types

```
typings install dt~angular --save
```

jsconfig.jsong file is in the root of my angular project along with typings.json and typings folder containing the angular module typings. I restarted vscode, still nothing.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JS projects, typings should be acquired automatically. Take a look at our documentation on [automatic type acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) for more info.

If automatic type acquisition is not working for some reason, try using `@types` instead of using `typings`:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/angular
```

These typings files should be automatically picked up for intellisense in VSCode.

Then if you still don't see proper intellisense, please [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new). Include your `jsconfig.json` and some example code.

Comment: This worked, so everything i did in my original post. is that not really required? should I just install @types/angular and create the jsconfig?

Comment: You ideally should only have to manage typings if you are working with a TypeScript project. Automatic type acquisition should handle things for JS but it may not be kicking in properly for some reason. If you do install typings, the modern approach is to use `@types` instead of `typings`